# Smarty - difference between register_object and assign_by_ref

Tags: php, smarty

These are two of the options I have for exposing a PHP object to a Smarty template. I know that there are syntax differences between the two, but I can't find any information on why you would use one over the other. Can anyone explain the differences?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 2):

If you use register_object() you can restrict the methods which can be called and also it means that you call the methods with a different (more Smarty-like) syntax:

```
<?php
// registering the object (will be by reference)
$smarty->register_object('foobar',$myobj);

// if we want to restrict access to certain methods or properties, list them
$smarty->register_object('foobar',$myobj,array('meth1','meth2','prop1'));
```

Template:

```
{* access our registered object *}
{foobar->meth1 p1='foo' p2=$bar}
```

From http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/advanced.features.php

Answer (score 2):

I think this page of smarty's documentation can help you : http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/advanced.features.php#advanced.features.objects

I don't think I could say much more than what's said there ; basically :

- [`assign`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.php) allows you to send data to the template ; some of these data can be objects
- [`register_object`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.register.object.php) allows more than that ; most important thing seems to be that you can specify which methods of the object can be used from the template file

The second possibility also gives a more "object-like" syntax, which looks like this *(examples copied from the doc)* :

```
{* access our registered object *}
{foobar->meth1 p1='foo' p2=$bar}

{* you can also assign the output *}
{foobar->meth1 p1='foo' p2=$bar assign='output'}
the output was {$output}

{* access our assigned object *}
{$myobj->meth1('foo',$bar)}
```

So, I'd say : choose the one that best fits your needs ;-)

Comment: This is Ok for Smarty 2. For Smarty 3, things have slightly changed. `register_object` became `registerObject`. See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.object.tpl